# Express.js route not working when uploaded to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, heroku

I am working on a node.js application and building my own restful API's.

The API's are called using Google fetch API, and are routed in my site using Express.js

```
const env = process.env;

export const nodeEnv = env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

export default {
    port: env.PORT || 8091,
    host: env.HOST || '0.0.0.0',
    get serverUrl(){
        return `http://${this.host}:${this.port}`;
    }
};
```

My config file I use to return the base URL of my site is as follows. Hence as example the URL for my restful webservice is shown in the network log of my browser as

```
http://0.0.0.0:8091/someRestfulLink
```

All working correctly locally, but upon uploading the server to heroku the restful request is always failing

```
Request URL:http://0.0.0.0:8091/confidentialityScaleAPI
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

This is what chrome browser shows with the restful request pending

What I noticed is if my local server is on the request is working! Which I think is cause the browser is using me as a default gateway

How to make the browser request the restful web service from heroku

Comment: when you successfully upload your build on heroku, it must provide you an URL. You can access your application through that link

Comment: it must be something like "blahblah.herokuapps.com"

Comment: you also can get that url from heroku dashboard.

Comment: Perfect changed the URLs in the rest requests into the heroku and it worked like a charm great work around!

Comment: :D so good to hear that...